# Blockly repeat block not working with both custom block and predefined blocks

Tags: loops, blockly

I'm working on an Angular project using Blockly and Phaser but repeat block is not working. Here is a small test to print `aa` 3 times.

[image]

But I received this error:

[image: JavaScript error message]

Here is the code used:

```
 <block type="controls_repeat_ext">
     <value name="TIMES">
         <shadow type="math_number">
             <field name="NUM">3</field>
         </shadow>
     </value>
 </block>
 //and for the function 
  
 run.on(event.POINTER_DOWN ,(image) => {
     eval(document.getElementById('code').innerHTML);
     console.log("running" )
 });
```

What should I add to make this repeat work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solved the problem by adding this code:

```
(Blockly as any).JavaScript.addReservedWords('div2');
        var code = (Blockly as any).JavaScript.workspaceToCode();
        try {
          eval(code);
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
        }
```